# Bash string change part of words

Tags: string, bash, shell, substitution

I need change a string before printing in `bash`. So I did:

```
${RETEZEC//./D}
```

Now I need to change one more thing, `-` for `_`. But no idea how to add it there? In the same step something like $`{RETEZEC//./D;//-/_} and i need one extra exeption for one - ?

Comment: There is echo "${RETEZEC//./D}"

Comment: Instead of commenting on your answer, update your question with the relevant info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to nest parameter expansion, you need two expressions:

```
foo=${RETEZEC//./D}
echo "${foo//-/_}"
```

You can, however, use an external tool to do this but I would recommend to stick with the native shell solution above.

```
$ echo "foo.-bar" | tr '.-' 'D_'
fooD-bar
```

Comment: Right and can i do somewhere an exception? like there is one - that i dont want to change but others yes.

Comment: @Vrsi Update your question with your actual requirements, you are being very vague here.

Comment: The square braces should not be there for `tr`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to replace `.` with `D` and `-` with `_`.

As others comment, you cannot do it in just one step. But you can use `tr`:

```
$ echo "$RETEZEC"
hel-lo_a.b.
$ tr '.-' 'D_' <<< "$RETEZEC"
hel_lo_aDbD
```

If you want to store the output in the same variable, do:

```
$ RETEZEC=$(tr '.-' 'D_' <<< "$RETEZEC")
$ echo $RETEZEC
hel_lo_aDbD
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
s='abc-def-foo'
echo "${s//-/_}"
abc_def_foo
```

Comment: yes but i want to change in one step . for D and - for _

Comment: @Vrsi That's not possible using parameter expansion.